# How can I have the computer randomly choose between people instead of numbers and only display it once?

Tags: batch-file

I want to have the computer pick between people instead of numbers and then remove that name from the list, but I don't know if I can in batch. I know how to make it pick a number but I want to assign people to a number and have that randomized. I also need it to be able to not print that person's name again but that, too, is beyond me. This is what I have :

```
:main
@echo off
SET /A test=%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1
set /a Susan=1
set /a Jeff=2 
set /a Nicole=3
set /a Eric=4
set /a Craig=5
set /a Jennifer=6
set /a Haley=7
set /a Ethan=8
set /a Lois=9
set /a Ann=10

echo %test%
echo.
pause
cls
goto main
```

Comment: You have to research and write code which attempts the specific task you have laid out in your question. Otherwise it will be assumed that your expectation is for someone else to design and/or create your code for you, _(which is off-topic here)_. BTW your `set /a` lines should not be using `/a` because they are not performing any arithmetic.

Comment: @Compo sorry it's just that I don't know enough code and I tried researching solutions and got nothing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly a direct code request.

Comment: Do you want to remove the item from the list completely, as in it should not longer be written in the batch file next time you run it? Or only when the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```bat
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set "_1=Susan"
set "_2=Jeff"
set "_3=Nicole"
set "_4=Eric"
set "_5=Craig"
set "_6=Jennifer"
set "_7=Haley"
set "_8=Ethan"
set "_9=Lois"
set "_10=Ann"

:main
cls & echo/ & set "test="
set /a "test=!RANDOM!*10/32768+1"
echo/ !_%test%! & pause && goto :main
```

---

To remove names in list and prevent to repeat:

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set "_1=Susan"
set "_2=Jeff"
set "_3=Nicole"
set "_4=Eric"
set "_5=Craig"
set "_6=Jennifer"
set "_7=Haley"
set "_8=Ethan"
set "_9=Lois"
set "_10=Ann"

:main
echo/ & set "test="
cls & set /p _!test!=<nul
set /a "test=!RANDOM!*10/32768+1"
if defined _!test! ( 
     echo/!_%test%! &  pause 
     set "_%test%=" && goto :main
    ) else (
     2>nul set _ |findstr \_[0-9]\= >nul && goto :main
     endlocal & exit /b
    )
```

Comment: that's perfect! tysm!

Comment: How can it be @EricRevell? It doesn't do what your question asked, does it?

Comment: You have see last editing @combo all times your comment help me to try understand better the question on my limited english.